# When converting to CSV UTF-8 with python, my date columns are being turned into date-time

Tags: python, excel, pandas

When I run the following code

```
import glob,os
import pandas as pd
dirpath = os.getcwd()
inputdirectory = dirpath

for xls_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputdirectory,"*.xls*")):    
     data_xls = pd.read_excel(xls_file, sheet_name=0, index_col=None)
     csv_file = os.path.splitext(xls_file)[0]+".csv"
     data_xls.to_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

It will convert all xls files in the folder into CSV as I want.
HOWEVER, on doing so, any dates such as 20/12/2018 will be converted to 20/12/2018 00:00:00 which is causing major issues with later data processing.

What is going wrong with this?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is "going wrong" per se. You simply need to provide a custom `date_format` to [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

> date_format : string, default None
>               Format string for datetime objects

In your case that would be

```
data_xls.to_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8', index=False, date_format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

This will fix the way the raw data is saved to the file. If you will open the file in Excel you may still see it using the full format. This is because Excel tries to assume the cell formats based on their content. You will need to right click the column and select another cell formatting, there is nothing that pandas or Python can do about that (as long as you are using `to_csv` and not `to_excel`).

Comment: Hmm, I did this and the same still happens, dates are still in the format 22/01/2019  00:00:00

Comment: @an159 Because you are probably opening the CSV file in Excel that assumes the format. Open the CSV file in a text editor or change the cell formatting in Excel. Your question now becomes an Excel question and not a Python question

Comment: This error still happens if I never open it into Excel, uploading as a CSV directly into a database causes errors as the procedures I am using cannot work with the date-time format

Comment: @an159 Suddenly there is a database involved? You should provide all these details in your question really. Again, try to open the file in a text editor. Are the dates in the format you expected? If so, then the problem lies in the way you are trying to read the file, not in how you save it

Comment: In whatever form I try and open this (newly generating each time) from excel, notepad to an online csv viewer the 00:00:00 remains on the end of columns

Comment: @an159 As long as you don't provide as much info as possible on the data you are working with (and how) there's not much more help I can offer.

Comment: When I run print(data_xls.head(5)) the time does actually show up as 00:00:00 before the change to csv as well! But In my excel sheet its in a date format 01/04/2019

Comment: @an159 of course it would, you are only changing the format when calling `to_csv`!

Answer (score 0):

if the above answers still don't work, try this?

```
import datetime as dt
xls_data['date']=pd.to_datetime(xls_data['date'], format="%d/%m/%y")
xls_data['date'] = xls_data['date'].dt.date
```

Comment: Other answers didn't work, but with your answer I don't have a 'date' column, I have several columns with various headers that I want to keep in date not datetime format

Comment: you can call those columns either by their names or their positions

Answer (score -1):

The original xls file is actually storing this fields as datetime.

When you open it with Excel - you seeing it formated the way Excel think you want to see it based on your settings / OS locale / etc.

When python reads the file, the date cells becomes python date objects.

CSV files are basically just text, it cannot holds datetime objects.

When python needs to write datetime object to a text file it gets the full text.

So you have 2 options:

1. Change the original file date column to text type.
   or the better option:
2. Use python to iterate this fields and change it the text format you would like to see in the csv.

I just tried to reproduce your issue with no success:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>xls_data = pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheet_name=0, index_cole=None)
>>>xls_data
    name       date
0  walla 1988-12-10
1   cool 1999-12-10
>>>xls_data.to_csv(encoding='utf-8', index=False)
'name,date\nwalla,1988-12-10\ncool,1999-12-10\n'`
```

P.S. Any time you deal with datetime objects you should test the result to see if anything change based on your pc locale settings.

Comment: My problem here is I am trying to do it for any random excel files that I come across regularly, so first option isn't possible.

2nd option not sure how I would go around doing, as I do not want to change everything into a date format, only certain current date-time columns that will not be in the same location every time

Comment: It's not you changing to date format, it is already a date object. You need to manually choose what format you want to print to the csv file.
Try to print the data_xls without cnverting to csv and see what it holds

Comment: When I run print(data_xls.head(5)) the time does actually show up as 00:00:00 before the change to csv as well! But In my excel sheet its in a date format 01/04/2019

Comment: As I wrote in my answer - your excel just displaying it the way excel think is most suitable for you, but in memory it holds an object that contains the time too. As mention in other comments - your question is become excel question, not Python.

Comment: No it isn't, I've tried opening in notepad++ as well and same issue

Comment: You open xls file in notepad++?

Comment: I opened the csv i created with notepad++

Comment: Try to run the code in python interactive shell like my updated answer, and provide the output in your question.